# ReactStrap Handle Input Implicit Submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

Whenever I press Enter when focused on the Input text box, the implicit submit from the Input element triggers a submission and reloads the page:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Col, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from "reactstrap";
import "./SearchBar.css";

class SearchBar extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: ""
    };

    this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    this.handleEnter = this.handleEnter.bind(this);
}

handleTermChange(e) {
    this.setState({ term: e.target.value });
}

handleSearch() {
    this.props.searchEngine(this.state.term);
}

handleEnter(e) {
    if (e.key === 13) {
      this.handleSearch();
    }
}

render() {
    return (
    <Form className="searchbox">
        <FormGroup row>
        <Label for="searchId" sm={2}>
            Search Engine
        </Label>
        <Col sm={10}>
            <Input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Sth"
            onChange={this.handleTermChange}
            onKeyDown={this.handleEnter}
            />
        </Col>
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup>
        <Col sm="2">
            <div className="">
            <Button
                onClick={this.handleSearch}
                className="btn"
            >
                Submit
            </Button>
            </div>
        </Col>
        </FormGroup>
    </Form>
    );
}
}

export default SearchBar;
```

I just want to trigger the search function with the handler as above, but avoid the implicit submit, i.e. same function when clicking on the `Submit` button. Otherwise it's just reloading the page and wash out the returned result.

What did I do wrong? I didn't experience this issue with basically the same pattern before.

Dependencies:

- "reactstrap": "^6.5.0"
- "bootstrap": "^4.1.3"
- "react": "^16.6.3"
- "react-dom": "^16.6.3"
- "react-scripts": "2.1.1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that it is the `<Form>` element that triggers the implicit submission. I change it to `<Form className="searchbox" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>` and add a new function:

```
handleSubmit(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.handleSearch();
}
```

Full working code modified from question:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Col, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from "reactstrap";
import "./SearchBar.css";

class SearchBar extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
            term: ""
        };

    this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    this.handleEnter = this.handleEnter.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleTermChange(e) {
        this.setState({ term: e.target.value });
    }

    handleSearch() {
        this.props.searchEngine(this.state.term);
    }

    handleEnter(e) {
        if (e.key === 13) {
        this.handleSearch();
        }
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.handleSearch();
   }

render() {
    return (
    <Form className="searchbox" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <FormGroup row>
        <Label for="searchId" sm={2}>
            Search Engine
        </Label>
        <Col sm={10}>
            <Input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Sth"
            onChange={this.handleTermChange}
            onKeyDown={this.handleEnter}
            />
        </Col>
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup>
        <Col sm="2">
            <div className="">
            <Button
                onClick={this.handleSearch}
                className="btn"
            >
                Submit
            </Button>
            </div>
        </Col>
        </FormGroup>
    </Form>
    );
}
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: I did a quick proof of concept based on the accepted answer. Clone/fork from https://github.com/nicc777/react-reacstrap-forms-demo - It is based on a React functional components using hooks for state.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent default event when `Enter` key pressed.

```
handleEnter(e) {
    if (e.key === 13) {
     e.preventDefault();
     this.handleSearch();
    }
}
```

`e.preventDefault()` tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

Comment: Ugh I don't find any difference after adding that one. It still reloads to `http://localhost:3000/?` after pressing enter.

Comment: Try to debug form onSubmit event.

Comment: And also try to add ‘e.stopPropagation()’ to input.

Comment: I found out that it is the `<Form>` element that triggers the implicit submission. I change it to `<Form className="searchbox" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>` and add a new function `handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.handleSearch();
  }`
Then it works!